# Syncronizing a multithreaded server

Tags: java, multithreading

Hello everyone i have created a multi threaded chat server that looks like this:

```
    public class Main {

    public static ServerSocket server;
    public static Socket connection;
    public static int backLog = 100;
    public static int numberOfConnected;
    public static boolean connected = false;
    public final static int potNumber = 6080;
    public static PrintWriter pw;
    public static Scanner input;
    public static int i = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        startServer();

    }
    public static void startServer(){
        try {
            server = new ServerSocket(potNumber, backLog);
            waitingForConnection();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    private static void waitingForConnection() {
        connected = false;
        i++;
        while (!connected) {
            try {
                if (connected) {

                }
                connection = server.accept();
                Server s = new Server(connection, pw = new PrintWriter(connection.getOutputStream()), input = new Scanner(connection.getInputStream()));
                s.start();
                numberOfConnected++;
                waitingForConnection();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }

}
```

The idea is that this is suppose to be a chat server so when one connects to the server it starts the following thread:

**threads**

```
    public void run(){
    while (connection.isConnected()) {
        if (input.hasNext()) {
            String fullMessage = input.nextLine();
            if (fullMessage.equalsIgnoreCase("Connect")) {
                connectHim();
            }else {
                chatMessage(fullMessage);
            }
        }

        }
    }

private void chatMessage(String fullMessage) {
    String name = fullMessage.substring(0, fullMessage.indexOf(" "));
    String message = fullMessage.substring(fullMessage.indexOf(" "), fullMessage.length());
    pw.println(name+": "+message);
    pw.flush();

}
private void connectHim() {
    String name = input.nextLine();
    pw.println(0);
    pw.flush();
    pw.println(1);
    pw.flush();
    pw.println();
    pw.flush();
    pw.println(name);
    pw.flush();

}
```

So my problem is the following:

if the user that is bound to thread 1 (this is an example) and the user bound to thread 2 sends a message to the server how will i send that message to the user bound on thread 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of options is to  use `Hashtable` or `HashMap` (just call `Collections.synchronizedMap(myMap)` in case of `Map` usage). When you start new Thread, give him  unique name (for example user nick name ) and put it to your collection where `key` - Thread name, and `value` - Thread as Object.

`if the user that is bound to thread 1 (this is an example) and the user bound to thread 2 sends a message to the server how will i send that message to the user bound on thread 1?`

For example you have `user1`, `user2`, `user3`. Now you build 3 Threads and put them to `HashMap`, like:

```
Map<String, Thread> threadMap = new HashMap<String,Thread>();
    threadMap = Collections.synchronizedMap(threadMap);



    YourThread th1 = new YourThread();
            threadMap.put("user1", th);

    YourThread th2 = new YourThread();
            threadMap.put("user2", th);

    YourThread th3 = new YourThread();
            threadMap.put("user3", th);

             ....

    Set<String> userSet = threadMap.keySet();

    Iterator<String> it = userSet.iterator();

    Thread currThread = null;

    while(it.hasNext()){
        String key = it.next();

        currThread = threadMap.get(key);

        // do something with currThread         
    }
```

Comment: Each time when you got new client, take his unique name and put to `Map`. If `user1` sent message to `user2`, run in loop (in my case `while`) and find Thread who has name `user2`. Extract his Thread and pass him the message.

Comment: Anyways use Tomcat to manage clients. As I know Tomcat handles about 800 clients per sec. And you don't need Threads/Maps ... Just in Tomcat set some `Servlet` and run with it

Comment: i am very glad for your response but not exactly sure what it does? where does it run the actual thread?

Comment: Witch one Tomcat or your example?

Comment: Well, all Threads (one per user) run in your application. You just store them into the `Map` and `key` - user1, 2, 3 are pointers to your Threads. So each time you extract them to pass them message.

Comment: can you by any chance explain the last part of you comment?

   Set<String> userSet = threadMap.keySet();

    Iterator<String> it = userSet.iterator();

    Thread currThread = null;

    while(it.hasNext()){
        String key = it.next();

        currThread = threadMap.get(key);

        // do something with currThread         
    }

Comment: Sure, it's only loop to extract Threads from Map by using keys: user1, user2, 3.  You have a lot documentation what is HashMap and how to work with it.